# Sum values in a dictionary

Tags: django, sum

Working on an Django app which can store equipments.

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 12, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to add All equipment prices. I have tried to do something like this:

```
total = Equipment.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

but if do this I cannot get to do any mathematical sums with this because it saying it's a `dictionary`.

I want my price value to be a number because I want to be able to do sums with the `total` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.all()` See [Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
Equipment.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

EDIT: You do not need the `.all()` in this case, you can get the value out of the dictionary returned by accessing the value returned in the [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
total = Equipment.objects.aggregate(price_sum=Sum('price'))
total_price = total['price_sum']
```

Comment: No it still does the same. This is not a integer but a dictionary as before. Unless there is a way to multiply and subtract an integer with a dictionary value (I dont know, is there a way?) Then there must be another way just to do it

Comment: i misread your question, i updated the answer to reflect your comment.